# How to extract ppl of this custom program?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a program that when I run, it prints something like this in command line:

```
file test.test: 427 sentences, 2433 words, 1186 OOVs
0 zeroprobs, logprob= -4914.55 ppl= 862.603 ppl1= 8731.65
```

But I only want to save the number 862.603 in an environment variable. How can I extract that single number from output of the program?

Comment: If indeed it is your own program, add an option to produce output in a machine-readable format, i.e. just the numbers, or variable=value, or JSON, or (shudder) XML.

Comment: What program is this? It's able to output it to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every answer I've seen thus far has had some deficiency, so I guess I'll go ahead and add this to the mix:

There are a couple of ways to do this.

My preferred way of doing it would be with grep's perl extension (`-P`):

```
var=$(myProgram | grep -oP 'ppl=\s*\K\d+\.\d+')
```

The `-o` flag tells grep to only print the matching string, which in this case is the number you're looking for.

Note that this is (almost) identical to sputnick's solution, but I've adapted it to read from your program directly via a pipe rather than a from a file.

I prefer that solution because you're essentially wanting to search for a particular string, which grep excels at.  The only problem is you also want to do a lookbehind, which is only supported in the perl regex extension.

So, if your grep doesn't support the perl regex extension, I would use sed:

```
var=$(myProgram | sed 's/ppl=\s*\(\d\+\.\d\+\)/\1/')
```

This assumes gnu sed, which is pretty common.  If you don't have gnu sed, then use this:

```
var=$(myProgram | sed 's/ppl=[ \t]*\([0-9]\{1,\}\.[0-9]\{1,\})/\1/')
```

The bottom line here is, you absolutely do ***not*** need more than one pipe to accomplish this task.  Opening pipes mean starting new processes, which is expensive.  In general, you want to open up as few pipes as necessary to accomplish your task when coding in the shell.

---

<sup>Edit</sup>

Just to point it out: sputnick's answer is now pretty much exactly what you want if you have the perl extension available.  The only difference between his and mine now is a small regex change (which you'll likely have to tweak yourself to suit your needs in the end anyways).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ var=$(<YOUR_COMMAND> | grep -oP "ppl= \K\d+\.\d+")
$ echo $var
862.603
```

If your distro lack the `grep -P` option, you should install `pcregrep`

**Edit**: Post edited to better suit your needs : I was using grep on a file, now that's on your command.

**Edit2**: this is an `awk` way to do it :

```
var=$(
    <YOUR_COMMAND> |
        awk '
            /ppl=/{
                for (i=0; i<NF; i++) {
                    if ($(i) ~ "ppl=" && $(i) > 1) {
                        print $(i+1)
                    }
                }
            }'
        )
echo $var
```

Comment: +1 now that it reads from a pipe.  I would have just commented on your answer directly, but nobody had presented the simple sed solution, so I decided to post an answer of my own.  But, like I said, this is my preferred solution if `grep -P` is available.

Answer (score 0):

`$ MY_ENV_VAR="$(myprogram |grep 'ppl= '|sed -r 's:^.*ppl= ([0-9\.]+).*:\1:'`)"

Comment: except that it also keeps lots of other output besides the number.

Comment: @lanzz My bad, i did not noticed multiple lines. Fixed! :)

Comment: @William Pursell - Why? I do it very often.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Why not piping grep to sed?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I often do something like this: `git status --porcelain|grep -E '^ M '|sed -r 's:^ M ::'|xargs git add` and for many other things I pipe grep to sed. I can't think of some peculiar behavior.

Comment: Well I can't think of a good reason *not* to pipe grep to sed, but I'm also having trouble thinking of a good reason *TO* do it as well.  sed will do matching just as well as grep.

Comment: sed can filter as well as grep.  `grep pattern | sed s/foo/bar` is identical to `sed -n '/pattern/s/foo/bar/p` or `sed -e /pattern/!d -e s/foo/bar/`.  Rather than doubling your IO by using grep to preprocess, just use sed to do the filtering.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, i was just looking if sed is capable of something like that. Good point! Though, it wont hurt to pipe either, it is just slower.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fgrep` to get only the line you want, and `awk` to get only the number you want:

```
program | fgrep ppl= | awk '{ print $6 }'
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure any flavor of `awk` would work, and I'm also pretty sure any solution would require certain utilities to be installed.

Comment: No need `grep | awk there`, it's useless : `program | awk '/ppl=/{print $6}'`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var=`./program | grep 'ppl=' | cut -d= -f3 | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/ppl1//g'`
```